# Convert unnamed json array to a proto file

Tags: c#, .net, grpc-c#

I'm trying to convert a json array unnamed to a proto file

```
[{
    "id": "dab44b72-e019-48f8-a519-b8f2d7c284f8",
    "name": "Test 1"
},
{
    "id": "b0dfa52e-fc6c-47ca-990e-ceee09c11926",
    "nome": "Test 2"
}]
```

But when using `JsonParser.Default.Parse<T>(json)` from `Google.Protobuf` I get the following error:

```
Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 'Expected an object'
```

This is the proto:

```
message TestRequest{
    repeated Test tests = 1; 
}

message Test{
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

If I name the array it works normally:

```
{
    "tests": [
        {
            "id": "dab44b72-e019-48f8-a519-b8f2d7c284f8",
            "name": "Test 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "b0dfa52e-fc6c-47ca-990e-ceee09c11926",
            "name": "Test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

In that case, what is the way to be able to convert an unnamed array to the list of the proto file?

Note: this conversion is generic for the application, and can be an array or just an object.